# whmcs gateway's _capture function never called, why so?

Tags: whmcs

When testing a whmcs payment gateway, it's capture function

```
function mygateway_capture($params)
{  
}
```

is never called. I have settings
Auto Redirect on Checkout:Automatically forward the user to the payment gateway.

What is happening now is, just after selecting the gateway and checkout it's redirecting to  site.com/cart.php?a=complete (Order Confirmation page)
without any transaction. Any idea why it's so?

Comment: Following up on this? Any update?